# How do i get enable /disable value from Magento admin?

Tags: magento-1, configuration, ifconfig

I have created a module, where admin can enable/disable and also select any value from select options.

Now I want this data to check that values, and according to that I want to give some conditions to display menu on header. (If admin enables this, the menu will be displayed in frontend).

How do i achieve this?

Please let me know any way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put below code in your system file

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
<tabs>
    <tab_name translate="label" module="Module_name">
        <label>Main tab name</label>
        <sort_order>500</sort_order>
    </tab_name>
</tabs>
<sections>
    <tab_name translate="label" module="Module_name">
        <label>Sub tab name</label>
        <tab>tab_name</tab>
        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
        <sort_order>110</sort_order>
        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
        <groups>
            <general translate="label">
                <label>General</label>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                <fields>
                    <enabled translate="label">
                        <label>Enabled:</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                        <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </enabled>
                </fields>
            </general>
        </groups>
    </tab_name>
</sections>
```

After that check Enable/Disable in your phtml file

```
    <?php 
$config = Mage::getStoreConfig('tab_name/general/enabled');
if($config){
echo "Enable from admin";
}else{
echo "Disable from admin";
}
```

Comment: It only displays else condition even i enabled it from admin panel..?

Comment: Print config value and check what value is in $config. After save both enable and disable from admin

Comment: Also, I have mention select option data,so now i want to get that perticular option data,how could i achieve this?

Comment: which kind of options data?

Comment: <dropdown translate="label comment">                            <label>Dropdown</label> <comment>Dropdown with global scope.</comment>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                         <source_model>ab_custommenu/system_config_source_dropdown_values</source_model>
                            <sort_order>30</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </dropdown>

Comment: I just menstioned some value inside dropdown,and now i want to get the data from dropdown?

Comment: You can get dropdown value using same as enable/disable. Mage::getStoreConfig('tab_name/general/dropdown');

Comment: Please give upvote also.

Answer (score 1):

**PHP/phtml files**

You can use this to check your enabled/disabled settings:

```
Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('path/to/enable_disable') // returns true or false
```

For all other config values you can use:

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('path/to/configfield') // returns config value
```

**Layout files**

In layout.xml files you can check **boolean** config values like this:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="append" ifconfig="path/to/enable_disable">
        <block>my_block</block>
    </action>
</reference>
```

If you want to use show something based on you config **string** values, you may need an helper method:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="append">
        <block_id helper="yourmodule/yourhelper/checkConfig"/>
    </action>
</reference>
```

> Your_Module_Helper_Data.php

```
public function checkConfig()
{
    $config = Mage::getStoreConfig('path/to/configfield');
    // your logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all call the value of enable disable fields from system.xml

```
$show = Mage::getStoreConfig('tab/general/enable_disable');
```

Then put your menu in if condition to display the header menu as below:

```
if($show == 1){
   echo 'Show Menu';
}else{
   echo 'Hide Menu';
}
```